# Where does the metric enter the picture in the definition of the standard topology?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

I am sure I will get slammed with this question, so perhaps I should just pretend I understand it, and keep on drawing balls with fuzzy margins... Or not.

So in the big ideas / motivation sphere of topology it sounds as though we are asked to think of $\mathbb R^n$ as a set, so that the idea of order is not yet defined. We forget numbers as in kindergarten, and just look at the set as a soup or powder of symbols. Fair enough, so now we need structure, and the first idea is to turn this set into at least a rubbery, elastic fabric where a topology  decides what elements appear consistently together in the subsets forming the topology: those points are somehow near each other, but the structure is still not a rigid line, plane or volume.

Presumably, not until we recover the idea of distance or metric.

However, before the metric makes its appearance, there is the sneaky $r$ that creeps in unannounced in the concept of the open ball used to define the standard topology.

So can someone break down the order of entrance of this sequence of reintroducing $\mathbb R^n$ as a topological space (or topological manifold)?

I apologize for the casual treatment of the subject. I don't mean to be disrespectful or controversial, and I am completely sure every step is seamless and completely well defined, I just don't understand the introduction of the distance $r$ in the definition of balls, because if feels like it is one step ahead of introducing a metric.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124676/discussion-on-question-by-math-tourist-where-does-the-metric-enter-the-picture-i).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have the intuitive order of progression somewhat backwards.

It sounds like you think we're expected to *start* with an abstract topological space, then discover that it's actually a *metric* space, and finally discover that it's actually $\mathbb R^n$.

It seems much more fruitful to go in the other direction: We *already know from the beginning* what $\mathbb R^n$ -- or at least $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^3$ -- look like, and have an intuition about what their open sets and convergence properties are.

Then we hope to be able to use that intution to help us come up with arguments about other spaces that *are not actually $\mathbb R^n$* but share some of its properties.

The first generalization we encounter here is metric spaces. They share *some* of $\mathbb R^n$'s properties, but not necessarily all of them. We can work in an abstract metric space, but *pretend* it looks like $\mathbb R^n$ when we picture situations to our inner eye. That's often helpful for *inventing* which kind of arguments ought to go through -- though of course we have to make sure the actual proofs about abstract metric spaces can actually be reduced to the metric-space axioms and don't the depend on incidental properties of $\mathbb R^n$ that are not shared by the *actual* metric space we're eventually going to apply our theorems to. It takes a bit of experience and training to get a reliable feeling for *how much* of one's $\mathbb R^n$ intution one can rely on for proofs -- that's what exercises are for!

Next we generalize to abstract topological spaces. They have even fewer properties in common with $\mathbb R^n$ than metric spaces have, which means that a theorem about topological spaces can apply in *more situations* than a theorem about metric spaces -- but on the other hand it's not all of the metric-space theorems that are still *valid* in the setting of abstract topological space.

Otherwise the extension goes much the same as the generalization from $\mathbb R^n$ to metric spaces: When carefully used, our intuition about the continuity of $\mathbb R^n$ can be helpful for discovering arguments that work for topological spaces in general.

---

It's a common temptation for textbook authors (or for that matter article/monograph authors too) to start with the most general concepts they have, as if that level of generality is the *fundamental truth* they want to teach, and treat concrete examples as imperfect approximations of that eternal truth. Most authors who fall into this "hyper-Platonic" trap probably do it inadvertently, sine it's easier to *write down* things in that order for someone who is already comfortable with the abstract concepts. Some authors, however -- such as most famously Bourbaki -- deliberately set out to present their material in that order.

Pragmatically, it usually much more *useful* -- not to mention *easier to learn* -- to keep the main examples in mind from the beginning, *before* we start generalizing.

- When you hear "topological space" you *should* be thinking "something that works in some respects like the geometric plane or space does".
- When you hear "ring" you *should* be thinking "something that works in some respects like the integers do".
- When you hear "vector space" you *should* be thinking "something that works in some respects (but different ones than those that matter for topology) like $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^3$ does".

Comment: +1 So the metric in the usual topology on $\mathbb R^n$ is there from the beginning. And, therefore, the claim in a presentation widely viewed on YT that $\mathbb R^n$ as a set is like powder is very poetic and such, but it is indeed always subject to very well prescribed kindergarten distances. Am I getting the gist of it?

Comment: @Mathtourist: I don't know the presentation you refer to, but the way you describe it doesn't _sound_ like it's very helpful ...

Comment: @Mathtourist: Specifically, it sounds a bit like the video is so preoccupied with driving home the small details of what the metric-space abstraction _is_ that it loses sight of what it's _for_.

Comment: [Here is the exact moment](https://youtu.be/93f-ayezCqE?t=2270) where this is discussed. I think the video is excellent, but I am just not presenting my question properly.

Comment: @Mathtourist: I think the lecturer is not at that point trying to make a claim about how one should think of $\mathbb R^2$ _in general_. His statements make more sense if the context is: The things you prove about $\mathbb R^2$ have a chance of being provable about _all sets in general_ if you think of it as "powder" while proving them. And things you prove about $\mathbb R^2$ have a chance of being true about topological spaces in general if you think of it as "rubber".

Comment: .... But $\mathbb R^2$ is not just a random abstract set -- its elements are the particular elements that $\mathbb R^2$ has, and we're free to know that and make use of the knowledge whenever we want to prove things about $\mathbb R^2$ _itself_. It's only when you _care_ about whether your arguments generalize to other spaces that you need to close your eyes and ignore some of what you know.

Answer (score 3):

Let me define a topological space from scratch. Consider the set of all sequences into the set $\{\square, \star\}$. Except that's too big. We want to shoot for the stars, not just live in boxes, so we only accept sequences with an infinite number of stars. But perfectionists are not tolerated either, so the sequence of all stars is also excluded. Call this space "starland".

The points of starland can be grouped by their beginning sequences. [Reworked:]We say that two sequences $S = (s_i)_{i \in \Bbb N}$ and $P = (p_i)_{i \in \Bbb N}$ are "$n$-neighbors" if there is some $k \le n+1$ such that

- for all $i < k, s_i = p_i$,
- if $k \le n, s_k \ne p_k$,
- for all $j$ with $k < j \le n, s_j = p_k$ and $p_j = s_k$.

For example, $$S = \square\square\square\star\star\dots,\quad P = \square\square\square\star\square\dots,\quad R=\square\square\star\square\square\dots$$
are all $4$-neighbors, no matter how they fill out the "$\dots$". $S$ and $P$ because their first $4$ elements are the same. $R$ because it agrees with them for the first two elements, and it ends with $\star\square$ where they end with $\square\star$ (the final $\square$ listed does not matter as it has index $5$. On the other hand, $T = \square\square\star\star\dots$ is a $4$-neighbor of $R$, but not of $S$ or $P$, since it disagrees with them at index $3$ but has the same value at index $4$. [end of Rework]

The set of all $n$-neighbors of $S$ is its "$n$-neighborhood". The collection of all $n$-neighborhoods all points $S$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$ forms a basis of neighborhoods for the topology on starland.

In case you missed it, as a topological space starland is just $\Bbb R$. Consider the stars to be $0$, and the boxes to be $1$, and it is the set of binary expansions of the open unit interval $(0,1)$, which is homeomorphic to all of $\Bbb R$. The rules for neighborhoods amounts to saying that $|S-P| <2^{-n}$ (or $2^{-n-1}$, depending on how you define $\Bbb N$).

[Added:] The reason for the rule that $P, S$ can disagree at some index $\le n$ and still be $n$-neighbors if they both immediately swap values at the next index and stay constant up to index $n$ is because $1 = 0.\overline{1}_2$. So if $P$ as a number ends in "$1\overline{000}$", and $S$ agrees with $P$ up to this point, but ends in "$0\overline{111}$", they represent the same number, and other numbers agree with that number up to $n$ bits if they have a binary expansion whose first $n$ bits agree with either form. If we just demanded all $n$-neighbors to have exactly the same first $n$ elements, half-open intervals such as $\left[1/2, 1\right)$ whose lower limits are dyadic fractions (denominators are powers of $2$) would be open, and the resultant space would be completely disconnected. Similarly, requiring an infinite number of stars rules out numbers ending in repeating $1$s, so that every real number in $(0,1)$ corresponds to exactly one starland point. [end of add]

---

But the point is, I defined the topology without reference to numbers (other than the indices), arithmetic operations, order (except on the indices), or distances. Even in the regular definition of the topology on $\Bbb R$, these are simply tools for defining the topology. They are not some integral part of that topology, which is just a collection of sets having useful properties. You can define those sets in other ways.

Comment: I see. I don't understand your prior paragraph about the sequences and the expression $b_n.$ I thought this latter function provided the position of the first one (or box), but I don't know what 'highest index' means.

Comment: The natural numbers start at $0$ or $1$, depending on who you ask, and increase forever. Those sequences start on the left, and go on to the right forever. So it is pretty clear which way the indices have to go.

Comment: I had not meant to be insulting. I expected my comment to be enough to allow you to figure out the problem (also, I deleted my original comment because I realized just after posting it that I had misread your question. Unfortunately, you still managed to see it and respond while I was typing in the correction.)  FYI - I suspect you've figured everything out now, but I added a paragraph explaining the reason for the last-box-disagreement rule for any later readers.

Comment: I will read your edit with attention, and hopefully it will clarify everything. I guess I got stuck at the rule "if $S$ has no boxes (1's) with index $<n,$ set $b_n(S) = n+1.$" In my mind this would mean that given two expansions: $S=0,0,0,1,1,\dots$ and $P=0,0,0,0,1,\dots,$ for example, if we calculated $b_n$ with $n=3,$ for $b_3(S)=4,$ and also for $b_3(P)=4.$ This sounds like not what we want, unless I am interpreting the index (i.e. position in the sequence) incorrectly. If you covered this part in the edit, don't worry; I'll go over it carefully later. Best wishes.

Comment: In the first case, $S,$ there is no $1$ in positions $1,2$ or $3,$ so we assign the value $3+1$ to $b_3(S)=4,$ and it does make sense because there is a $1$ in position $4.$ However, in $P,$ the position $4$ is also a $0,$ so I don't see why we would assign also $4$ to $b_3(P)=3 +1.$

Comment: It makes no difference in that case. Because the only point in the $b_n$ definition is for determining whether or not $P$ and $S$ are $n$-neighbors, and that is only affected when $b_n \le n$. I chose $n+1$ just as a way to get something out-of-range. Since neither $S$ nor $P$ has a box with index $\le 3$, the only way for them to be $3$-neighbors is by having their first three bits the same (which they do).

Comment: FYI - I decided to abandon the last-box concept and rewrite the requirement in a way that is more wordy, but hopefully easier to follow.

Comment: Very nice! In the sentence 'The collection of all $n$-neighborhoods all points $S$ for all $n∈N$ ', did you really meant "points" or "sequences"?

Comment: Both. I defined the set as a collection of sequences. But when I topologize the set, its elements are points in a topological space. They may be sequences under the hood, but as far as topology is concerned, they are just points.